# Is wp_insert_post exactly the same as publishing a post through the core UI?

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'm building a plugin that will call the `wp_insert_post()` function. I need to know if it is functionally identical to posting via the UI. For example, would other plugins (I'm thinking particularly of JetPack) share to social media or are there additional steps to replicate manually publishing (or scheduling) a post?

Comment: Probably not. Have you checked WP source what happens on publishing? I'd assume a couple of actions are probably firing that are not inside `wp_insert_post()`. (But that is only an assumption)

Comment: @kero that was what I was worried about. I don't much fancy crawling around inside JetPack or similar to find out what they hook.

Comment: Actually, `wp_insert_post()` does do the actions hooked on `save_post` and `post_updated`. So the answer is yes, although you will need to specify post_data like publish date, sanitize post_name if necessary, post_meta etc if you want something other than the defaults (and the $post->ID when updating, otherwise you'll create new posts every time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit more to the answer than just `wp_insert_post()`. That is the canonical way to insert a post and what the Classic Editor used to submit all of the post information at once.

The REST API (and thus Gutenberg) changes it a tad but running `wp_insert_post` initially just to setup a post in the db, then separately adds all of the meta data and taxonomies, etc (see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php?rev=49172#L577 ).

In terms of Jetpack's Publicize feature, `wp_insert_post` will work just fine. We look for the `wp_insert_post` hook to sync up the post data used for the social media share ( https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/projects/packages/sync/src/modules/class-posts.php#L118 ).